# How to add audio every x time [ffmpeg]

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio

I have a file video.mp4 and file audio.mp3, how to with the audio inserted every 2 seconds of video
i try it but doesn't seem right. Please help me!

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=2s:all=true[delayed];[0][delayed]amix=duration=shortest" -c:v copy output.mp4
```